# What exception type should this be?

Tags: exception, x86

When executing this instruction I got an exception

```
LFS   ESI,PWORD PTR [EBP+12]
```

From this page http://wiki.osdev.org/Double_Fault#Double_Fault
*Any PUSH or POP instruction or any instruction using ESP or EBP as a base register is executed, while the stack address is not in canonical form.*

So i think it should be an **Stack-Segment Fault** here.
But the system gives an general protection exception(0D).

Could anyone tell me why the result is this?

Comment: What kind of system are you on, where you can load segment registers?

Comment: @Bo Persson , this is peculiar OS called DMX. This is used to load a far pointer in a process stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General protection fault for an LFS occurs when:

1. the segment selector index you are
   trying to load is not with the
   descriptor table limits
2. the segment is in the descriptor
   table, but it's not a readable data
   segment
3. your privilege level is higher
   (meaning less privilege) that the
   privilige level for the descriptor.

So, the problem is not the instruction itself, but the segment descriptor table.

See chapter 3 in the Intel Software Developer’s Manual Volume 3A:
[http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/?wapkw=(Intel+64+and+IA-32+Architectures)](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/?wapkw=%28Intel%2064%20and%20IA-32%20Architectures%29)